# Making Http PUT request with query strings using C#

Tags: c#, rest, http, iis, webclient

I tried below code as I wanted to send a http PUT request to a REST Api. The sample request looks like

```
http://localhost/SomeWebServices/some/something/setsomething?ID=12121212&Number=121212&Product=BUISCUITE&EffectiveDate=2015-10-22

WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.QueryString.Add("CustomerNumber", "bla");
request.QueryString.Add("AccountNumber", "bla"); 
request.UploadString(new Uri(BaseUrl + ServiceEndPoint), "PUT", String.Empty);
```

When I debug the code I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error,  Am I doing the correct thing to make a HTTP PUT request ?   Is there a way to intercept the request to see if its in correct format. My service is hosted in local IIS instance. Although I have used `WebClient()` you are more than welcome to share your elegant approach if there is a better & easy way. Thanks.

Comment: Send some credentials with your request

Comment: There is no way to answer your question based on information you've provided. Answer to off-topic "Search for HTTP debugging tools" part of your question is Fiddler.